# Replace keyframes with custom ones in a video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to use ffmpeg to extract all keyframes from a video stream (H.264 for example) and then (after I do some changes to them) inject them back into the same positions, retaining the other data, without reencoding the stream?

I want to use this to visualise how video compression works, and make some cool effects. If H.264 is not the best codec to use for this, is there a better codec to use for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 0):

The end result would be corrupt video, but as long as the ids are preserved, yes, you can corrupt a file that way.

Comment: It may not be obvious from the phrasing, but I also want to know *how* to do it, not just if it is possible.

Comment: It’s all documented in ISO 14496-10.

Comment: Using ffmpeg...

Comment: @IllidanS4 Not possible, as ffmpeg does not have such bitstream filtering / modifying capabilities. You would have to write your own program to splice the bitstream into the respective NAL units, write out the image data, and merge them back in.

Comment: @slhck Is there any other tool that can accomplish this?

Comment: @IllidanS4 If I knew one, I would have provided an answer. It's actually not that easy, and depends on what exactly you want to modify in the intra-frames. What would be possible is modifying the H.264 reference software (JM) directly.